# ng-click not firing within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show different graphs for different schools, and the button does not fire when clicked.

I have this in my html file:

```
<button ng-repeat="datarow in testData | unique:'school_name'" ng-click="showlinegraph(testData)">
   {{datarow.school_name}}</button>
```

And my controller:

```
 $scope.showlinegraph = function(data) {
    $scope.showgraph = ! $scope.showgraph;
    console.log(data);
  }
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, and the issue i think has to do with the ng-repeat because a button without it, successfully calls the controller method.

```
<button ng-click="showlinegraph(testData)">
    Toggle Graph
  </button>
```

The button with ng-repeat doesn't even depress when clicked on.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `button` in a `span` or `div` and putting the `ng-repeat` on that element? I would expect it to work as you have it, but it might be something with the `ng-repeat` being on the same element.

Comment: What is testData ?

Comment: yes. i have tried rapping it in a div and putting the ng-repeat in a div, it does not work unfortunatly.

Comment: tried in codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/odwXaE , works fine, please share testData json object to debug easily

Comment: testData is coming from a database thru and http request.

Comment: @FrankieKlerer,,please provide sample testData  and you are seeing buttons right, did you inspect from developer tools?

Comment: if you can still see the codepen, i edited it and it does not hide/show the div

Comment: i can see the buttons, and in the inpsect the ng-click is in each button

Comment: @FrankieKlerer, unfortunately i cant see your changes , unless you save it and share updated url

Comment: https://codepen.io/frankieklerer/pen/zjzvvP

Comment: @FrankieKlerer, https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GdEpqb , p tags must be inside the div which is having ng-controller to make ng show  work

Comment: @FrankieKlerer, any luck now, is it working ?

Comment: @FrankieKlerer This is really strange that the `ng-show` isn't working, I would recommend an edit to your post, I'd change the title to "ng-show not respecting variable value" and update the content to match what is in the codepen. The `ng-click` is definitely firing, and the variable is definitely having it's bool value swapped, but the `ng-show` isn't respecting the value of the variable.

Comment: hello - i figured it out and it had nothing to do with angular. There is a d3 svg on the page and the svg container was overlapping, making anything underneath un-clickable. some of my buttons were underneath and some weren't which was causing for all this weirdness. Thanks for all your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try in the controller to find the `school_name` and just print it in the button label. perhaps the `ng-click` event couldn't fire because you're using `ng-for` too...

I mean, in you controller file do a `foreach` and find the `school_name` in the object then store the `school_name` into a variable and print that variable in the button. And must work properly.